# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to display the scheduled jobs with a name, status and description. This works very well, however when i try to sort it using order by `ScheduledName`, I get an error telling me i have an incorrect syntax and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
SELECT * FROM sysjobs Job

SELECT * FROM sysschedules 

SELECT * FROM sysjobschedules

SELECT 
    SC.name AS ScheduledName, Job.name AS JobName, 
    Job.enabled AS JobStatus, Job.description AS JobDescription 
FROM 
    sysjobs Job 
ORDER BY 
    ScheduledName;
INNER JOIN
    sysjobschedules SCH ON Job.job_id = SCH.job_id
INNER JOIN
    sysschedules SC ON SC.schedule_id = SCH.schedule_id
```

Comment: You can not have an order by before inner join

Comment: Order by at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an incorrect Syntax. Change to:

```
USE msdb
GO

SELECT * FROM sysjobs Job;

SELECT * FROM sysschedules; 

SELECT * FROM sysjobschedules;

SELECT SC.name AS ScheduledName, Job.name AS JobName, Job.enabled AS JobStatus, Job.description AS JobDescription FROM sysjobs Job 
inner join sysjobschedules SCH
on Job.job_id=SCH.job_id
inner join sysschedules SC
on SC.schedule_id=SCH.schedule_id
ORDER BY ScheduledName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
SELECT SC.name AS ScheduledName, Job.name AS JobName, Job.enabled AS JobStatus, Job.description AS JobDescription
FROM sysjobs Job
ORDER BY SC.name;
```

The semicolon terminates the query.

When you remove the semicolon, you also need to move the `ORDER BY`to the end:

```
SELECT SC.name AS ScheduledName, Job.name AS JobName,
       Job.enabled AS JobStatus, Job.description AS JobDescription
FROM sysjobs Job inner join
     sysjobschedules SCH on
     Job.job_id = SCH.job_id inner join
     sysschedules SC
     on SC.schedule_id = SCH.schedule_id
ORDER BY SC.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SC.NAME AS ScheduledName
    ,Job.NAME AS JobName
    ,Job.enabled AS JobStatus
    ,Job.description AS JobDescription
FROM sysjobs Job
INNER JOIN sysjobschedules SCH ON Job.job_id = SCH.job_id
INNER JOIN sysschedules SC ON SC.schedule_id = SCH.schedule_id
ORDER BY SC.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

`Order By` should be in the end

```
USE msdb
GO

SELECT * FROM sysjobs Job

SELECT * FROM sysschedules 

SELECT * FROM sysjobschedules

SELECT 
   SC.name AS ScheduledName, 
   Job.name AS JobName, 
   Job.enabled AS JobStatus, 
   Job.description AS JobDescription 
FROM sysjobs Job 
inner join sysjobschedules SCH
on Job.job_id=SCH.job_id
inner join sysschedules SC
on SC.schedule_id=SCH.schedule_id
ORDER BY ScheduledName;
```